# Yet another white space between divs

Tags: html, css

Sorry to ask the same question many before me have asked... I have read lots of these and they all say change

```
margin: 0;
```

There is a gap between the two divs (div class ="heady" and div class="menus") I just can't seem to get rid of the white space, hopefully it is clear enough, let me know if its not.

Thanks James.

html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>website</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style1.css" />
    <body>
    <div class="heady">

    <br></br>
    <h1><a class="header" href="index.html">website</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="menus">

    <ul>
        <il><a class="list" href="x.html">About</a></il>
        <t> | </>
        <il><a class="list" href="y.html">Beginners</a></il>
        <t> | </>
        <il><a class="list" href="z.html">Advanced</a></il>
        <t> | </>
        <il><a class="list" href="contact.html">Contact</a></il>

    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*general rules*/

html,body {
    font-size:11pt;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: black;

    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

h1 {  
    font-size: 25pt;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color: grey;
} 



/*header section rules*/
div.heady {
            height: 200px;
            width: 760px;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: grey;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
             margin: 0;
 }

a.header {
    text-decoration: none;
 }
 a.header:link, a.header:visited, a.header:active,a.header:hover  {
    color: red;
    margin:0;

 } 

 div.menus {
 padding: 0;
 margin:0;
 background-color:black;
 width: 760px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:12pt;

 }

 a.list {
 margin:0;
 }
```

Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jbHQ/1/).

Comment: There are no spaces in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/ZDEWd/

Comment: There is no white space here: http://jsfiddle.net/7K4BP/

Comment: @lucuma, MichaelRobinson: You need to turn off the "normalize CSS" checkbox

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Thanks I never even noticed that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers apply default styles to ceratin elements. In this case it's `ul` that gets some margin. Note that this margin separates the divs even though the divs themselves have no margins.

Use

```
ul { margin: 0; }
```

or include a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Firebug plugin for Firefox? Even if you don't already use firefox, you should download it along with the firebug plugin. With Firebug you can look at an element in your source code and see the styles that are being applied, the layout (width/height, padding, margin), and even manipulate the styles to view what a change in your CSS would do.

I HIGHLY recommend it!

[Download Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
[Download Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  .heady { display:block; }
  .heady { margin:0; padding:0; }
  .heady { line-height:100%; /* or even 0 (if no text present) */ }
```

the content can fool here, but 1 or all 3 of those should tame the beast across browsers.

google for a "css reset" too